# Getting error while importing my json file in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am getting error while importing json file.

Below is my error.

[image: I am getting this error]

My Json File:

{"city": "ACMAR", "loc": [-86.51557, 33.584132], "pop": 6055, "state": "AL", "_id": "35004"}
{"city": "ADAMSVILLE", "loc": [-86.959727, 33.588437], "pop": 10616, "state": "AL", "_id": "35005"}
{"city": "ADGER", "loc": [-87.167455, 33.434277], "pop": 3205, "state": "AL", "_id": "35006"}
{"city": "KEYSTONE", "loc": [-86.812861, 33.236868], "pop": 14218, "state": "AL", "_id": "35007"}
{"city": "NEW SITE", "loc": [-85.951086, 32.941445], "pop": 19942, "state": "AL", "_id": "35010"}
{"city": "ALPINE", "loc": [-86.208934, 33.331165], "pop": 3062, "state": "AL", "_id": "35014"}
{"city": "ARAB", "loc": [-86.489638, 34.328339], "pop": 13650, "state": "AL", "_id": "35016"}
{"city": "BAILEYTON", "loc": [-86.621299, 34.268298], "pop": 1781, "state": "AL", "_id": "35019"}
{"city": "BESSEMER", "loc": [-86.947547, 33.409002], "pop": 40549, "state": "AL", "_id": "35020"}
{"city": "HUEYTOWN", "loc": [-86.999607, 33.414625], "pop": 39677, "state": "AL", "_id": "35023"}
{"city": "BLOUNTSVILLE", "loc": [-86.568628, 34.092937], "pop": 9058, "state": "AL", "_id": "35031"}
{"city": "BREMEN", "loc": [-87.004281, 33.973664], "pop": 3448, "state": "AL", "_id": "35033"}
{"city": "BRENT", "loc": [-87.211387, 32.93567], "pop": 3791, "state": "AL", "_id": "35034"}
{"city": "BRIERFIELD", "loc": [-86.951672, 33.042747], "pop": 1282, "state": "AL", "_id": "35035"}
{"city": "CALERA", "loc": [-86.755987, 33.1098], "pop": 4675, "state": "AL", "_id": "35040"}
{"city": "CENTREVILLE", "loc": [-87.11924, 32.950324], "pop": 4902, "state": "AL", "_id": "35042"}
{"city": "CHELSEA", "loc": [-86.614132, 33.371582], "pop": 4781, "state": "AL", "_id": "35043"}
{"city": "COOSA PINES", "loc": [-86.337622, 33.266928], "pop": 7985, "state": "AL", "_id": "35044"}

Comment: can you post a portion of your file you are trying to import?

Comment: post json file that you are importing

Comment: i have updated my json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Quit the mongo shell !

**mongoimport** is an independant command

Just execute the second command.

I'm not in 2.6 mongodb but I don't think there are so many changes

Comment: Could u please help ?? how to import more then 1 collection from a json file.

Comment: For more than one collection you need to use a **mongorestore**. The mongoimport is only for one collection, an other solution could be to execute one mongoimport for each collections you like

Comment: In my above json file i have city,loc,pop etc object i want this all in different collection like city,loc,pop how it can be achievable with mongoDb

Comment: If you use those multiple collections, you're using a relationnal like model" MongoDB will not be the best solution .... Your model according to the JSON file seems to be way better !